# Does inference from a heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix follow the t-distribution or the normal?

Tags: confidence-interval, covariance, heteroscedasticity, robust, t-distribution

**Background**

I'm currently looking into how reliable confidence intervals are on bounded scores (EQ-5D) and I compare regular asymptotic, robust and botstrap-based confidence intervals. The robust (alias heteroscedacity-consistent) perform really well but have a significant over-coverage in small samples. This gets better if I use the normal distribution instead of the t-distribution, unfortunately I'm finding conflicting data on what distribution to use.

**Question**

Is there a general recommendation for using the t-distribution instead of the normal distribution? (A reference would be lovely)

**Details**

I'm using the `sandwich` package in R together with "HC3" & "HC4m" covariance estimators generated by the `vcovHC` function. I started using th code from StackOverflow's [question on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817182/vcovhc-and-confidence-interval), after adapting it a little I have the following code:

```
confint.robust <- function(object, parm, level = 0.95, HC_type="HC3", ...){
  cf <- coef(object); pnames <- names(cf)
  if(missing(parm))
    parm <- pnames
  else if (is.numeric(parm))
    parm <- pnames[parm]

  a <- (1-level)/2; a <- c(a, 1-a)
  pct <- stats:::format.perc(a, 3)
  fac <- qt(a, object$df.residual)
  ci <- array(NA, 
              dim = c(length(parm), 2L), 
              dimnames = list(parm, pct))
  ses <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(object, type=HC_type)))[parm]
  ci[] <- cf[parm] + ses %o% fac
  ci
}
```

**Googling this**

I've tried to find the answer by Googling but the results have been slim, below is a short summary of the most interesting articles that I've found.

The sandwich package's [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich-OOP.pdf) has some pieces that I'm not sure exactly how to interpret, all the examples use z-tests but I'm not sure to why and they have this text i section 5:

> ```
> Predominantly, sandwich estimators are used for inference, such as partial t or z
> tests of regression coefficients or restriction testing in nested regression models
> ```

From Haan and Levin's ["A Practitioner’s Guide to Robust Covariance Matrix Estimation"](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wouterdenhaan.com%2Fpapers%2FHAND30.pdf&ei=RWosUoOeMKT54QSuoYDYCQ&usg=AFQjCNEq9h8Mu-02_iy_gMPY_Vy9URQveQ&bvm=bv.51773540,d.bGE&cad=rja) indicates that this is known at least for the HAC although it didn't give me that much more to work with:

> However, to the extent that the estimated HAC covariance matrix
>   exhibits substantial mean-squared error (MSE) in finite samples, the
>   resulting inferences may be severely distorted. For example,
>   substantial variation in the estimated standard error generally causes
>   a t-statistic to take large values (in absolute terms) more frequently
>   than predicted by the limiting standard normal distribution, thereby
>   leading to a tendency to over-reject the null hypothesis in a
>   two-sided test.

Going to the original 2011 paper from [Cribari-Neto et al](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10182-010-0141-2) where they propose the HC4m alternative they use the quasi-t distribution. The paper is unfortunately beyond my scope of comprehension but it indicates that the t-distribution might not be the way to go:

> Under the null hypothesis, it does not follow a Student t distribution
>   (hence the name ‘quasi-t’), but it does have a limiting standard
>   normal distribution

Unfortunately I'm a little lost by their $\tau$ definition:

$$\tau=\frac{c'\hat{\beta}-\eta}{\hat{var(c'\beta)}}$$

In the article they explain that $\eta$ is a given scalar, and $c'$ is a p-vector, unfortunately this does not aid my understanding of what the formula is doing... Although the hypothesis test seems familiar: $|\tau|>z_{1-\alpha/2}$

Comment: HAC covariance matrices are typically derived asymptotically. Since the t distribution is meant for use in (small) finite samples, the normal is typically used with HAC standard errors.

Comment: @Charlie thanks, I found "an answer" that will have to do for now, see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prof. Cribari-Neto was kind enough to suggest an article for this topic:

[F. Cribari-Neto and M. da G. A. Lima, “Heteroskedasticity-consistent interval estimators,” Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation, vol. 79, no. 6, pp. 787–803, 2009.](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949650801935327#.UkPvyX9R0bU)

In this article he uses **the normal distribution for the confidence intervals**. As I wrote in my question this is also supported by my resampling study on the subject where the t-distribution gives considerable over-coverage (96-97 %) for samples $\leq 50$.

#### A quick review of the t-distribution

Unfortunately I’m not certain to exactly certain to why this is. From what I understand [Gosset’s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) student t-distribution is based upon the uncertainty of the $S$ estimation of $\sigma$. A vital part to the t-distribution are these two formulas:

$$Z = (\bar{X}_n-\mu)\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$$

$$V = (n-1)\frac{S^2_n}{\sigma^2}$$

Where he noted that the $V$ follows the $\chi^2$-distribution. Now if we combine these two to get the t-value:

$$T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{V/v}} =  \frac{(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}}{\sqrt{(n-1)\frac{S^2_n}{\sigma^2}/v}} = \frac{(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}}{\frac{s_n}{\sigma\sqrt{v}}\sqrt{(n-1)}}=\frac{(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\sqrt{n}\sqrt{v}}{s_n\sqrt{(n-1)}}$$

By working out that $ν = n − 1$ it further simplifies to:

$$T = \frac{(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\sqrt{n}}{s_n}$$

I guess the $V$ estimation is changed in this case, if the uncertainty of the $S_n$ is less then we're left with the $Z$, in formula language:

$$V = \lim_{S_n \to \sigma} (n-1)\frac{S^2_n}{\sigma^2} = (n-1)$$

Hmm... I hope that I got the formulas right, Wikipedia often has minimized the simplification sections and I thought it would be nice to have it here just to follow what exactly is happening (for us not working with maths on an every-day basis I find the connection between the raw form and the simplified a little hard to digest).

It would be great if someone here could explain exactly why this happening with the HC-estimate.